# Angularjs remove row from table when pushed to a second table

Tags: angularjs, html

I have 2 tables.
I'm gettings rows in the first 1 and pushing every single row to the second table

```
$scope.secondtablelist=[];
$scope.pushrows = function (row) {
    $scope.secondtablelist.push(row);
};
```

I want to remove that the pushed from the first table when it's pushed to the second to obligate the user to push the raw only 1 time Any idea ?

Comment: `$scope.firsttablelist.splice($scope.firsttablelist.indexOf(row), 1)`

Comment: 100%, Thank you )